# How to convert Activity into Fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, fragment

I want to convert this Activity into Fragment, how can I do that?
Can you show me how? A help is need. THANKS!
Here's my code.
I want to convert this Activity into Fragment, how can I do that?
Can you show me how? A help is need. THANKS!
Here's my code.
I want to convert this Activity into Fragment, how can I do that?
Can you show me how? A help is need. THANKS!
Here's my code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Commbody extends Activity {
TextView cmd,desc,cmddesc,syntax,options;
int id;
DBHelper dbhelper;  
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.desc);

        id = getIntent().getIntExtra("COMMAND_ID", 0);
        SQLiteDatabase db = (new DBHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();



       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT linux_comm._id, linux_comm.comm_desc, linux_comm.syntax, linux_comm.options FROM linux_comm WHERE linux_comm._id = ?", 
                new String[]{""+id});

        if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
        {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                cmddesc = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TextView4);
                cmddesc.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("comm_desc")));

                syntax = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TextView5);
                syntax.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("syntax")));

                options = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.TextView6);
                options.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("options")));

        }

    }

    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How will converting it to fragment help you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read up on how Fragments work.

What you are trying to achieve makes no sense.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html